# JQuery mobile handling links (return false)

Tags: jquery-mobile, anchor, hyperlink

I'm planning on using JQM to make a simple mobile web app, and I'm having problems getting this simple functionality to work: when I click on some links (not all of them), I want to be able to first process some data, and then depending on that outcome, sometimes continue the link action (I like the whole transitions and ajax things), and sometimes don't.

The important part is that I want to preserve the normal JQMobile transitions and stuff for the links, just sometimes prevent them (for example for validation and things like that).

I've tried with: return false, preventDefault (and in combination with stopPropagation), and data-ajax="false", and none hav worked, they all redirect.

Could somebody tell me the correct way to to this in JQMobile? Just in case it's important: I'm using anchor links, using [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html) to test.

Thank you in advance, Jennifer.

RESOLVED: Added answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to set a `click` event on the links for which you want to prevent a default behavior.

In the example below, we add a class `special_link` to the link for which we want to do something special before being redirected to another page.

When we click on the "special" link, we check if a given condition is followed or not before deciding to redirect the user to another page.

The redirection (with all the transitions stuffs) to another page (`page_2` in our example), is done manually, with the following code:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#page_2", {
  transition: "slide",
});
```

Fo more information about the method `$.mobile.changePage`, you can check the online doc:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

In following example, if you type a `1` in the text input, you'll not be redirected. Otherwise, you'll change page.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {

        // Setting the click event for our special link
        $(".special_link").click(function() {

            // IF SOME CONDITION THEN... (Here, if we typed a 1 in the text input)
            if($('#my_value').val()=='1') {

                // We do not change page
                alert("We stay where we are");

            } else { 

                // We change page. In this example: page 2
                $.mobile.changePage( "#page_2", {
                transition: "slide",      // You can define the transition 
                                          // you want + other parameters

                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- PAGE 1 -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page_1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>

                <input type="text" id="my_value"/>

                <!-- A SPECIAL LINK -->
                <a href="" class="special_link">Special link</a>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- PAGE 2 -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page_2">
        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
            <a href="#page_1">Go back to page 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hey first thanks for your answer! I have been able to achieve the same thing, although I didn't know about the changePage, it looks really handy, so thanks for that, but... My problem is specifically that I would like to NOT change page sometimes, basically emulate the return false in a form submission for example. 
If $something followLink else nothing.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly your problem, but you may simply have to add an `IF` condition in the click statement? I modified the code so you can have a look.

Comment: Well, my problem is precisely that I couldn't find what would stop the redirect. Although I appreciate your help, all of this is explained in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured out a pretty decent way to do this, without it feeling like a kludge. I'm simply going to avoid using  tags, and use buttons instead, this way I normally intercept them and if I want to transition, I use the changePage JQM method. Works like a charm. Thanks [Littm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1261007/littm) for that tip, and I hope this is useful for somebody else in the future.